# Fetching error when installing Heroku

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, heroku

I tried to install Heroku in Ubuntu using this script

```
wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
```

and I get this error while installing heroku-toolbelt package

```
Failed to fetch http://toolbelt.heroku.com/ubuntu/./foreman-0.60.0.deb  Size mismatch
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I tried to download "http://toolbelt.heroku.com/ubuntu/./foreman-0.60.0.deb" manually to `/var/cache/apt/archives/` but didn't work with the same error.

Any ideas to get this thing installed ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mirror in your software sources might not be up-to-date. Try changing the mirror in software sources.

Also try out the alternate way of installation. Using the below commands

```
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://toolbelt.herokuapp.com/ubuntu ./'
wget -O- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/apt/release.key | apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install heroku-toolbelt
```