# Heroku Toolbelt install - header over 360 characters

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, heroku

I am trying to install the heroku toolbelt on my Ubuntu 12.04.

I am getting the following errors when I run the script from the heroku website:

```
$ wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh

W: Failed to fetch http://toolbelt.herokuapp.com/ubuntu/./Release.gpg 
Got a single header line over 360 chars

W: Failed to fetch http://toolbelt.heroku.com/ubuntu/./Release.gpg 
Got a single header line over 360 chars [IP: 54.225.184.218 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://toolbelt.heroku.com/ubuntu/./Packages  Got a
single header line over 360 chars [IP: 54.225.184.218 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://toolbelt.heroku.com/ubuntu/./en_GB  Got a
single header line over 360 chars [IP: 54.225.184.218 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://toolbelt.heroku.com/ubuntu/./en  Got a
single header line over 360 chars [IP: 54.225.184.218 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://toolbelt.herokuapp.com/ubuntu/./Sources  Got
a single header line over 360 chars

W: Failed to fetch http://toolbelt.herokuapp.com/ubuntu/./Packages 
Got a single header line over 360 chars

W: Failed to fetch http://toolbelt.herokuapp.com/ubuntu/./en_GB  Got a
single header line over 360 chars

W: Failed to fetch http://toolbelt.herokuapp.com/ubuntu/./en  Got a
single header line over 360 chars

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old
ones used instead.
```

I have searched through here and found [similar questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202451/fetching-error-when-installing-heroku), and tried the fix in the question with no luck.

open to all ideas on fixing this issue!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345651/heroku-toolbelt-fails-to-install-with-407-ubuntu-precise/14398261#14398261
Best answer I found solving all the heroku Installation problems..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`install-ubuntu.sh` adds `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/heroku.list`. However, it adds `http://...` instead of `https://...`. Change that to https.

I downloaded `install-ubuntu.sh`, added an `s` to the script, and then ran it. it's at least moving past that step now.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Thank you @John Tseng

Comment: Any clue what changed recently? I never needed this before (installing toolbelt on TravisCI just stopped working today). I did your fix  but then got the error `The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/https could not be found`. Is there a way to fix it without having to apt-get another package? Would like to make a PR with comprehensive fix https://gist.github.com/schneems/8430456/raw/4fd3af050c37ba6f5b06dda3e846d0ad33c87f9a/gistfile1.txt

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be a bug in apt, http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=658346
It is reported to be fixed in `0.8.16~exp13` version of apt package.

Unfortunately, latest apt in Precise is `0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.16`. That means, it is up to you to wait till apt is updated in official repositories, build yourself a newer apt from source or use someone else's PPA like `ppa:vnwildman/ppa`.

**EDIT:** I can no longer advise that specific PPA because I've just wrecked my `dpkg` multiarch setup with it.

When it comes building from source, it seems to be sufficient to add

`deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main restricted universe multiverse`

to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`, and afterward use `apt-get builddeps ###` and `apt-get source ###` to install build dependencies and download package source from Quantal. When source is downloaded, I prefer use `debuild` from `devscripts` package to compile and package downloaded sources in single command.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu try the standalone heroku toolbelt. It worked for me:

```
wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install.sh | sh
```